# age calculator in javascript with running clock and NO months, days or seconds

Tags: javascript, calculator

There are many age calculators in js online, only all of them with months and days.

I'm looking for something thats saying 31.5345343543 years old with a running clock (on 10ths of seconds), running from a birth date and time. I know how to do it in php, but with php you can't make it a running clock :( And my JS just isn't good enough to do both..

This is what I tried to far (took code from a running countdowntimer):

```
<script>
var start = new Date('09/15/1982 03:29 PM');
var timer;

function age() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = now.getTime()-start.getTime();
    document.getElementById('age').innerHTML = (distance / 3155692600); // seconds in a year, times 100 to get the . right. 
}

timer = setInterval(age, 1);
</script>
<div id="age"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Are you having trouble making one? If so, share your code and the errors you get. If you're just looking for a finished solution, this is off-topic for SO.

Comment: It runs, sorta works, just gives a dot after 5 digits instead of 2, and any Math.round or Math.floor stops the running part. I would like it to format it with a dot after 2 digits (years) and then 9 digits (100s of seconds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
<script>
var start = new Date('09/15/1982 03:29 PM');
var timer;

function age() {
    var now = new Date();
    var age = now.getTime()-start.getTime();
    var year = (age / 31556926000); // seconds in a year * 1000
    document.getElementById('age').innerHTML = year.toFixed(9);
}

timer = setInterval(age, 1);
</script>
<div id="age"></div>
```